# How do I generate ngroups from a comparison function?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a function that compares rows in a dataframe:

```
def comp(lhs: pandas.Series, rhs: pandas.Series) -> bool:
  if lhs.id == rhs.id:
    return True

  if abs(lhs.val1 - rhs.val1) < 1e-8:
    if abs(lhs.val2 - rhs.val2) < 1e-8:
      return True

  return False
```

Now I have a dataframe containing `id`, `val1` and `val2` columns and I want to generate group ids such that any two rows for which `comp` evaluates to true have the group number. How do I do this with pandas? I've been trying to think of a way to get `groupby` to achieve this but can't think of a way.

MRE:

```
example_input = pandas.DataFrame({
    'id' : [0, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'value1' : [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.1],
    'value2' : [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.1]
})

example_output = example_input.copy()
example_output.index = [0, 1, 2, 2, 0]
example_output.index.name = 'groups'
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] of input/output data?

Comment: @quant, your post is of *low* quality, atm. MRE offers one I/O dataframe but the func likely uses two, with different column names. Not to mention that you're type hinting pandas' Series as parameters and expecting a boolean, which is very confusing.

Comment: @Timeless `comp` doesn't take dataframes as inputs, it takes two rows of the same dataframe and compares them, returning a boolean to indicate whether or not they belong in the same group.

Comment: @Timeless I get it now, this is actually a graph problem, the goal is to cluster groups based on original id or distance

Comment: And the function attempts to describe what should happen for **pairs or rows** within the DataFrame (`True` = connected)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to cluster rows that either belong to the same group, or that are close in distance. For that compute the distance with [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) to identify the close points, and create a graph with [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) to identify the connected components:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
from itertools import combinations

# example input
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'id' : [0, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'value1' : [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.1],
    'value2' : [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.1]
})

thresh = 1e-8
cols = ['value1', 'value2']

# create graph based on already connected ids
G = nx.compose_all(map(nx.path_graph, df.index.groupby(df['id']).values()))

# add pairs of values with distance below threshold as edges
G.add_edges_from(pd.Series(combinations(df.index, 2))
                 [pdist(df[cols])<thresh]
                )

# form groups based on the connected components
groups = {n: i for i, c in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G))
          for n in c}
# {0: 0, 4: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2}

# update index based on above dictionary
df.index = df.index.map(groups)
```

Output:

```
   id  value1  value2
0   0     1.1     2.1
1   1     1.2     2.2
2   2     1.3     2.3
2   2     1.4     2.4
0   3     1.1     2.1
```

Graph (only based on IDs ; numbers are the original indices):

[image]

Graph (after taking the distance into account):

[image]

Comment: Wow, I didn't realise how complex my question would be. Thanks for this, I'll try it out soon.

Comment: @quant maybe there's a simpler approach, but honestly I doubt it. You have to use a graph library or a recursive merging of the groups. Merging groups/sets is indeed not a trivial task and can easily be performed incorrectly ;)

Comment: Note that I computed the euclidean distance here, which is not exactly the same as using a threshold on each individual coordinate, but I believe this is what is really expected.